# Where can i store authentication tokens in client side

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

When my users are authenticated by username and password they receive an authentication token, I need to use this authentication token to authorize some asp.net WebAPI calls. To do this i stored the authentication token in the browser local storage, so it is the safest way to store that token and still accessible in my javascript code to make API call's?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/best-place-to-store-authentication-tokens-client-side

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a **Cookie** or **HTML5 Local Storage** for the purpose.

---

***Cookies*** are more common I guess:

**JQuery:** $.cookie()

Just create a cookie with:

```
$.cookie("MyNewCookie", "Whats inside");
```

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

**JS:**
document.cookie()

To create a new cookie:

```
document.cookie = "NewCookie=TheCookiesValue";
```

You could use this script from https://javascriptexamples.info/code/javascript-get-cookie-name/ to retrieve the cookie:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

---

***HTML5 Local Storage:***

I don't know a lot about this one, yet. But start here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use cookies or local storage. I would prefer to have the token saved in global context of your application, for security considerations.

Based on the SPA frameworks, you can store them more elegantly. Say, if you are using Ember.js you can use a singleton and inject the token in ember data store, which makes the API calls or similar to that.

Hope this helps.